# cannot create unique index over {EDs._id: 1 } with shard key pattern { _id: "hashed" }

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to index the embedded documents where the main collection is using the hash sharding.
Sample Structure:

```
class ED(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = StringField(primary_key=true)
    meta = {
        'indexes': [{'fields': ['EDs.id'], 'unique': True}]
    }

class D(Document):
    id = StringField(primary_key=true)
    EDs = EmbeddedDocumentListField(ED)
```

Now, I've added a sharding in collection D.

```
sh.shardCollection("db.d", { "_id" : "hashed" } )
```

Now since I've added indexes on ED's id, it is not allowing me to save the document.

```
$cmd failed: cannot create unique index over { EDs._id: 1 } with shard key pattern { _id: "hashed" }
```

However, when we remove this meta from ED it works. It also works when I remove sharding.
So, how can we achive this indexing on embedded document ED's id?

Comment: You should probably give a little more information. I do not even recognize the type of code. For questions regarding MongoDB, shell syntax and BSON documents improve the likelihood of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Is this Python ? some context will help

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work by actually including the shard key in the unique index itself.

Answer (score 3):

'Unique' option for createIndex, in the literature of MongoDB says: *"The option is unavailable for hashed indexes"* [createIndex Options](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types)

So if you remove the option: {'unique': True} when you create the index, you will not get this error anymore.